# Django ModelForm not retrieving field's value

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using two ModelForms to create na user with a Profile instance. Profile ModelForm has a single field. I'm doing form.save(commit=False), setting the required field (country) other than the one in the form and saving. I get an error saying that 'country_id' cannot be null.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


class ProfileRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['country']
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your Account'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user)
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('activation_email_sent')
    else:
        user_form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileRegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: When you save the `user`, the post_save triggers `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` which can never work when `country` is not nullable and has no default!

Comment: I tried to make country nullable but it got saved as null.

Comment: You need to remove that post_save fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. I removed the `post_save`, made `country` nullable and saved `user` and `profile` separately. Thanks for the help.

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
```